# Поиск в бд Sqlite кириллицы. C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, кириллица

Проблема такая: в бд все ищется очень хорошо, пока это английский, но на русском не ищет вообще ничего. Даже если учитывать регистр и даже если запись состоит из одной буквы. Что можно сделать? Уже почти все по этой теме перерыл, но не могу найти решение. Так как многие пишут, что у них ищет русский, но только с учетом регистра букв.

Вот поисковый запрос

```
var klients = db.Query<Klient>("SELECT * From Klient WHERE " +"brand"+ " LIKE '" + ""+ "%'");
```

Comment: А вы какую библиотеку используете `SQLite.net-pcl` или `SQLite-net-pcl` ?

Comment: тип поля у вас nvarchar? тогда добавьте `N` перед условием поиска, чтобы получилось `LIKE N'строка%'` - скорее всего поможет.

Comment: @PashaPash, Тип поля Varchar у меня.

Comment: @Bulson, Ставил из Nuget пакетов, 
Стоит sqlite-net (без pcl в названии)

Comment: А вы пробовали открыть файл базы в какой-нибудь утилите и сделать аналогичный запрос? Я проверял в SQLite-manager для FireFox, запрос с русскими значениями работает

Comment: Вот сейчас только проверил: `var person = _DB.Query<Person>("SELECT * FROM People WHERE FullName LIKE '" + name + "%'").First();` я использую `SQLite-net-pcl ` все работает. Да, и действительно поиск зависит от регистра.

Comment: @ИгорьАбрамян varchar не дружит с не-латинскими символами. поменяйте на юникодовый nvarchar, и добавьте N в перед кавычками в like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это поможет:

```
/// <summary>
/// Класс реализует COLLATION для русских строк в SQLite
/// </summary>
[SQLiteFunction(Name = "UTF8CI", FuncType = FunctionType.Collation, Arguments = 2)]
public class SQLiteCaseInsensitiveCollation : SQLiteFunction
{
    private static readonly System.Globalization.CultureInfo _cultureInfo =
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru-RU");

    public override int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        return String.Compare(x, y, false, _cultureInfo);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Класс реализует uppercase русских строк для SQLite
/// </summary>
[SQLiteFunction(Name = "CYR_UPPER", Arguments = 1, FuncType = FunctionType.Scalar)]
public class SqLiteCyrHelper : SQLiteFunction
{
    public override object Invoke(object[] args)
    {
        return args[0] != null ? ((string)args[0]).ToUpper() : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Надо добавить пример как пользоваться этими классами

Comment: Перед соединением с БД зарегистрировать ф-цию:  SQLiteFunction.RegisterFunction(typeof(SQLiteCaseInsensitiveCollation));

Comment: и все же в коде как будет? Вот у меня соединение такое: `_DB = new SQLiteConnection(_FileDB);` `_DB.CreateTable<Person>();` ну так как сюда запихать SQLiteFunction

Comment: И кстати у меня вообще нет такого класса SQLiteFunction. У меня установлен пакет sqlite-net-pcl

Comment: Так и будет (кусок рабочего кода):              bool result = false;

            SQLiteFunction.RegisterFunction(typeof(SQLiteCaseInsensitiveCollation));

            connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);

Comment: А что насчет отсутствия SQLiteFunction?

Comment: У меня System.Data.SQLite.dll

Comment: Значит у меня не прокатит. У меня другая библиотека

Comment: Вы какой nuget пакет ставили?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/files/SQLite%20for%20ADO.NET%202.0/

Answer (score 0):

Для [Microsoft.Data.Sqlite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SQLite/) можно создать функцию. Например:

```
var connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=mydatabase.db");
connection.CreateFunction("lower", new Func<string, string>((s) => s.ToLower()));
```

Теперь в запросе можно использовать функцию lower(*значение*). Например:

```
var command = new connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM myTable WHERE lower(Фамилия)=lower('иВаНов')";
connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```